# How to delete row based on the selection in Listbox?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Userform listBox that displays data from the worksheet. I want to delete the worksheet row based on the selection on listBox.

The code deletes the row above, not the selected row according to listbox.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    If lstDisplay.Selected(i) Then
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `i + 1`....? Also, better not to delete in a loop. Use `Union` to create a range to delete, and delete it *after* the loop. Also use `Long`, not `Integer`.

Comment: Deleting through upto 65k rows will take many minutes, and integer will only work up to row 32k-ish so if your last row is data beyond this it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this on some test data...

Sub CommandButton3_Click()

' Will move data to array and then move wanted data
' to a second array and repaste that back on to the spreadsheet
' currently TestCondition is the comparison in column A
' Change Sheet1 if your worksheet name is different.


Const COMPARE_COL As Long = 1
Dim a, aNew(), nr As Long, nc As Long
Dim r As Long, c As Long, rNew As Long
Dim TestCondition As String, tmp

a = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
nr = UBound(a, 1)
nc = UBound(a, 2)

ReDim aNew(1 To nr, 1 To nc)
rNew = 0
TestCondition = lstDisplay.Selected(a)

For r = 1 To nr
    tmp = a(r, COMPARE_COL)
    If tmp <> TestCondition Then
        rNew = rNew + 1
        For c = 1 To nc
            aNew(rNew, c) = a(r, c)
        Next c
        TestCondition = tmp
    End If
Next r

Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange = aNew

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much but unfortunately the code is not working. Do you have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

When deleting items from a list, always work from the end to the beginning, never from beginning to the end. In top of that, there's no need to select when you want to do something, so I would advise the following (not tested):

```
For i = Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Row - 1 DownTo 1
    If lstDisplay.Selected(i) Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Step -1
```

By the way: 65356 looks so familiar and similar to 65536 (`2^16`). I suspect there's a typo here :-)